# Handling Suggested Edits: User Updated Answer for Updated Library

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently got this suggested edit in my review queue and skipped it because I did not know the proper way to handle it.  Here's the post in question: [Bootstrap 3 - show collapsed navigation for all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860263/bootstrap-3-show-collapsed-navigation-for-all-screen-sizes/21865785#21865785).  (I didn't know how to post the actual edit suggestion here)

The editor added a few lines of code to the accepted answer and commented it as "For Bootstrap 3.3".  The question being asked is directly regarding Bootstrap 3, but was asked & answered over a year ago.

The edit is constructive considering most people would be using the updated version of the library (Q says v3, no minor version is stated), but I didn't want to take action on the review of that item without knowing what the consensus is on the appropriate action in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Changing code like that is generally frowned upon, and such an edit should be rejected. The appropriate thing is for the edit-suggester to instead post a full answer for the new version.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for he insight!