# Should you delete your answer if the "Main answerer" has asked and updated his answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

So, I just encountered this case in the "Late answers" review line: A user provided an update to the "Main answer" (the one that was validated and had the most votes).

After he posted, the author of this "Main answer" commented, asking if he could add the additional elements to his own answer, and the guy said yes of course.

Here is a picture of what happened:

[image]

I was wondering in this case, should the guy that provided the update in the first pace delete his answer, since the "Main" one has been updated? I would go for yes, since it would be useless to have two time the same content on the same page. At the same time, if the "Main" answerer doesn't want to give credit, then no one will know where the update came from.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: *should the guy that provided the update in the first pace delete his answer* - By "should" do you mean "obligated to"?

Comment: I was wondering if it happened to me, what should I do? But I guess yes 'obligated to' would be right in this case.

Comment: I would say Ali should delete and Sebastiano should give proper credit.

Comment: @David Arenburg I totally agree with that, but as there is no way of being sure the credit is going to stay (dumb people are everywhere), some people might not want to delete their answer. If I was in Sebastiano's place, of course I would update and give credit ,and If I was Ali I would delete as soon I as saw the update. But as not everyone would do as I would, is there already a rule for this kind of cases?

Comment: @nicovank Edits to a post are kept in the revision history.  If someone edits attribution of another's content out of an answer there would be a record of that extremely inappropriate edit, and it would be able to be reversed.  The edit would also count as activity, drawing some attention to the post.

Comment: @Servy ok yes I guess that is true, I was not considering history of the edits, as Sebastiano posted a new answer and didn't propos an edit to the post itself, which [according to this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291860/handling-suggested-edits-user-updated-answer-for-updated-library), is a bad practice. I will summarize and post an answer.

Comment: Poor Ali only has 1 point.

Comment: @nicovank, I would not consider a question on meta which has a total of 2 votes to be anywhere close to showing a consensus as to what people think is a good way to handle a situation. It might be a good way, it might not, but just 2 votes doesn't indicate much. In addition, [that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291860/3773011) was specifically about how to handle reviewing the edit of a random user changing code in an accepted answer. For that specific situation, IMO, there is a consensus (elsewhere) that such edits should be rejected (edit should be a comment or separate answer).

Comment: @martinjakubik he is suspended, he also has no badges ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say you're "obligated to" delete your answer, but it would be common courtesy to do so. There is already enough noise on SO threads, no need to add more.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you're reading this question, you are in either of the three following cases:

#### You want to provide an update to an existing question

In this case, just [create a new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291860/handling-suggested-edits-user-updated-answer-for-updated-library) with the necessary updates.
The user that posted the original answer might then be in the second case, which is...

#### A user posted a new Answer completing yours

As said by [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy), you do not need to ask for the user's permission, as all user content posted on SO is licenced under CC-Wiki.

So you can directly include his Answer's content in your post, providing you give him enough credit, for example with his name and link to his profile.

*Ex*: Update by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

#### The original poster has included your Answer, giving proper credit

You can now delete your post.

Comment: You do not need to ask someone's permission to incorporate the content of their answer into your own.  You *are* obligated to cite the content that is theirs.  All user content posted on SO is licenced under CC-Wiki, giving everyone in the world the right to publish the content, so long as it is cited.

Comment: Also, it might make sense for the author of the updated answer to make it community wiki.

Comment: Re. your last sentence: you *can*, but there is no obligation. First of all if someone is including the contents of my answer into its own without major changes, it would be appropriate for them to make their own answer community wiki, secondly you always retain the right to gain reputation from the content you produce, hence you have no obligation to remove your answer, even if it is subsumed by an other people.

Comment: @Bakuriu, While I agree the choice to remove the subsumed answer is a personal choice (which is potentially per-person context dependent, and getting rep for it is good), I do not agree that incorporating the information into the other answer automatically implies the person *should* make it community wiki. Making it a community wiki should, again, be a personal choice (which, again, for most would be context depended (e.g. based on relative contributions)). However, as has been said, credit *must* be given for the new text, if copied. Credit *should* be given if rewritten, but the ideas kept.

Comment: I know not everything needs to be 'rep' related, but, to the extent that a user has provided useful information worthy of 'rep', and only ends up getting 'verbally acknowledged' instead, then I feel this breaks things. SO has a very formal system of providing feedback for useful contributions, and that is the 'rep' system. And while, this may be seen by some as mere 'nerd points', it's not, it is in fact the way the community recognises contributions (and members who provide them) as useful. I.e. it benefits the community far more than it does individual users, so it shouldn't be bypassed.